# Continue to elif after a nested if-statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

If the nested if-statement doesn't fulfill a condition, how do I continue on to the outer if? Eg. I have this (very impractical) example:

```
a = 2

if( a > 1 ):
    if( a == 3 ):
        print "yes"
elif( a == 2 ):
    print "yes"
```

I want a == 2 to be checked next. How would I do this?

(I have multiple conditions in that nested if that I need to check so I'd rather not have a huge string of and/or statements in that one outer-if. I also have more than one elif statement so I don't want to mash all the elifs together under that nested one.)

A deeper example:

```
b = 8

if( a > 1 ):
    if( b == 3 ):
        doSomething()
    elif( b == 4 ):
        doSomethingElse()
    elif( b == 5 ):
        more()
elif( -1 <= a <= 1 ):
    asd()
elif( a < -1 ):
    if( b == 7 ):
        asdfasdf()
    elif( b == 8 ):
        asasdf()
```

Comment: `if a > 1` followed by `elif a == 2` **never** makes any sense. Because 2 is larger than 1. Maybe you just want `if`, not `elif` there. Or wrap it in a function so you can use `return`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you expect this to be clear to a computer?

```
if a > 1:
  # ANYTHING
elif a == 2:
  # ANYTHING
```

by definition will never execute anything in the second block.

I believe your intend might be more along this lines:

```
def action():
  if a > 1:
    if b == 2:
      doSomething()
      return
    if b == 3:
      doSomethingElse()
      return
 if a == 2: # Note: NO elif!
   doDefaultForA2()
   return
 showError("Unknown command")
 return
```

There are multiple ways to achieve this behaviour. I like the `function+return` pattern, because it structures code nicely. Another way is to use a `handled` flag:

```
unhandled = True
if a > 1:
  if b == 2:
    doSomething()
    unhandled = False
  if unhandled and b == 3:
    doSomethingElse()
    unhandled = False
if unhandled and a == 2: # Note: NO elif!
  doDefaultForA2()
  unhandled = False
if unhandled:
  showError("Unknown command")
```

(You can obviously put in a number of shortcuts here by using elif. But using explicit "if unhandled" makes the code more verbose about the logic *and* easier to add new options.)

Comment: Yes, it was a very bad example and did not show why I actually needed to ask this for the real code. I was thinking of breaking out of the nests, but return is better so thank you.

Comment: -1 The first option maintains the `a > 1, a == 2` redundancy. The whole `unhandled` caper in the 2nd option is an ugly unreadable unmaintainable mess.

Comment: @JohnMachin: you didn't fully understand the inquiry. It's not about "a" and the actual tests, just that they overlap, and the actual decision whether the case was handled happens in the lower levels. If it makes you happy, replace any integer test with "`complexTest1(a)`".

Comment: @Anonymouse: You didn't read the the latest edit of his question; he's removed the overlap!

Comment: Indeed, he's changed the question after accepting my answer. But only the "deeper" example. The first one is still if a > 1, elif a == 2, where he wants "if unhandled and a == 2" instead.

Answer (score 5):

combine the conditions and flatten the nesting:

```
a = 2

if ( a > 1 and a == 3 ):
    print "yes"
elif ( a == 2 ):
    print "yes"
```

Comment: `a == 3` implies `a > 1`.  If that's how you want to combine them, then there's no need for the `a > 1` at all.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the example is just indicative but your original question was to understand nested if-else, association, scoping ....

In Python, unlike Algol-like languages we don't have demarcated blocks (for ex. in C we use '{' to make a block. Here all blocks are via proper white-space indentation. Its like the philosophy, what you read is what you would get. This off-course is to adhere to the design philosophy "Code Readability".

In similar context, whether the subsequent `if/else` statement would be part of the outer or inner if statement depends on how it was indented.

Your example

```
a = 2

if( a > 1 ):
    if( a == 3 ):
        print "yes"
elif( a == 2 ):
    print "yes"
```

Here `elif` is part of the outer `if`, because that's what it reads or rather looks and that's how it was indented. Instead the below modified version of your code

```
a = 2

if( a > 1 ):
    if( a == 3 ):
        print "yes"
    elif( a == 2 ):
        print "yes"
```

Would make the logic apparently different. More because the indented `elif` block is now aligned with the inner if.

This is now much easier compared to the following C Code

```
if (a > 1) 
   if (a == 3)
      printf("Hello World\n");
else if (a == 2)
   printf("Yes");
```

Can you easily say with which if the `else if` is associated?

Comment: I do understanding the scoping and get why indenting the elif would yield a completely different result, I just don't know whether there's a way to go onto the next check--to achieve the effect of rewriting the elif in that nested block, without actually having to rewrite it.

Comment: @idlackage, the answer would be no. This is what python is. If you need to change the behavior you need to change your code.

Comment: @idlackage: what Abhijit says, except that it applies not only to Python but also to all programming languages that are not jokes or academic curiosities.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 2
if a > 1:
    if a == 3:
        print "a is 3"
    elif a == 2:
        print "a is 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

What outcomes do you want:

- print "yes" when a is 2 or 3
- otherwise do nothing

Translate that into *simple* code

```
if a in (2, 3):
    print "yes"
```

"deeper" example: You don't need some of your nesting. The following *simple* code is equivalent to yours:

```
if a == 1:
    if b == 7:
        print "yes 1, 7"
    elif b == 8:
        print "yes 1, 8"
elif a == 2:
    print "yes 2"
elif a == 3:
    print "yes 3"
elif a == 4:
    print "yes 4"
elif a == 5:
    print "yes 5"
```

By the way, please read [PEP 8](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and have a look at some of the code written by others... `if( foo == 9 ):` is an unfamiliar pattern which causes readers to slow down over the speed humps, and possibly avoid that road in future.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing this to make it easier to read and possibly easier to write would be to put the choices for one of the checks into a dictionary.  This will only work if you actually are checking equality, but may work for you.

```
#used when a>1
bchoices1 = {}
bchoices1[3] = doSomething
bchoices1[4] = doSomethingElse
bchoices1[5] = more

#used when a==1
bchoices2 = {}
bchoices2[7] = asdfasdf
bchoices2[8] = asdfas

if( a > 1 ):
    bchoices1[b]()
elif( a == 2 ):
    asd()
elif( a == 1 ):
    bchoices2[b]()
```