# Invalid syntax of elif nested in elif

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am currently working on a project for my CSE class and we are meant to ask users for information on their car rental, then print out their balance and other information. Each user has either a budget (B), daily (D), or weekly (W) code which all have different equations for calculating the final balance of the account. I tried to use if and elif statements for each codes, however I keep getting an invalid syntax error while nesting if statements inside of an elif statement. How could I resolve this error to continue working on the project? Thank you!

```
answer = input("Would you like to continue? (Y/N)? ")

while answer == 'Y' or answer == 'y': #user inputs information if they reply yes to the prompt
     customer_code = input("Please enter Customer code (B/D/W): ")
     days_rented = int(input("Please enter the number of days rented: "))
     initial_miles = int(input("Please enter the original mileage of the rental: "))
     final_miles = int(input("Please enter the new mileage of the rental: "))

     mileage = final_miles - initial_miles #calculating other information
     weeks = (days_rented / 7)
     average_miles_d = mileage / days_rented
     average_miles_y = mileage / weeks

     if customer_code == 'B': #budget customer
         balance = ((40 * days_rented) + (.25 * mileage))

     elif customer_code == 'D': #daily customer
         if average_miles_d < 100:
             balance = ((60 * days_rented)    
         elif average_miles_d >= 100:
             balance = ((60 * days_rented) + (.25 * (average_miles - 100)))

     elif customer_code == 'W': #weekly customer
         if average_miles_w < 900:
             balance = (190 * weeks)    
         elif average_miles_w > 900 and average_miles_w < 1500:
             balance = (100 * weeks)    
         else:
             balance = ((200 * weeks) + (.25 * (average_miles_w - 1500))
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` on this line: `balance = ((60 * days_rented)`

Comment: Unrelated: the code for weekly customers doesn't handle `average_miles_w == 900`.

Comment: You don't need any brackets at all on that line

Comment: Get yourself a good IDE, like PyCharm. It will make it hard for you to create unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Adding the parenthesis fixed it, thank you!

Comment: And thank you for the other fixes! We are forced to use spyder for the most part, but I'll look into PyCharm!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continue to elif after a nested if-statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365714/continue-to-elif-after-a-nested-if-statement)